# Error loading rstudio

Tags: software-installation, rstudio

```
Error: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl1.0.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl1.0.0' has no installation candidate
```

general info:

```
Linux MacBookPro-NJ 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
RStudio version 1.3.1056
```

Launch file: `/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio %F`

Comment: The instructions you are following are for Ubuntu 18.04 and older. The `libssl1.0.0` package was dropped after Ubuntu 18.04, replaced in newer releases by `libssl1.1`

Answer (score 0):

You have to download RStudio for [Ubuntu 18 / Debian 10](https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.3.1056-amd64.deb)

> [image: https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download]

and install it using

```
sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-1.3.1056-amd64.deb
```

to get dependencies satisfied automagically.